# Cannot apt-get upgrade Ubuntu Server

Tags: apt, dpkg

I tried to a upgrade this morning and encountered errors. Ran apt-get -f install and got this error below. I don't recall installing any quantal packages.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-quantal:
linux-image-generic-lts-quantal depends on linux-image-3.5.0-39-generic; however:
Package linux-image-3.5.0-39-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-lts-quantal (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-quantal:
linux-generic-lts-quantal depends on linux-image-generic-lts-quantal; however:
Package linux-image-generic-lts-quantal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-lts-quantal (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-generic-lts-quantal
linux-generic-lts-quantal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I purged the quantal packages (linux-image-generic-lts-quantal, linux-generic-lts-quantal) and ran apt-get update then upgrade. All is well.